# multiply columns of data frames

Tags: r

I have been scratching my head over this. I have two data frames: `df`

```
df <- data.frame(group = 1:3,
                 age = seq(30, 50, length.out = 3),
                 income = seq(100, 500, length.out = 3),
                 assets = seq(500, 800, length.out = 3))
```

and `weights`

```
weights <- data.frame(age = 5, income = 10)
```

I would like to multiply these two data frames only for the same column names. I tried something like this:

```
colwise(function(x) {x * weights[names(x)]})(df)
```

but that obviously didn't work as `colwise` does not keep the column name inside the function. I looked at various `mapply` solutions ([example](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/145917.html)), but I am unable to come up with an answer.

The resulting `data.frame` should look like this:

```
structure(list(group = 1:3, age = c(150, 200, 250), income = c(1000, 
3000, 5000), assets = c(500, 650, 800)), .Names = c("group", 
"age", "income", "assets"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

  group age income assets
1     1 150   1000    500
2     2 200   3000    650
3     3 250   5000    800
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sweep()` is your friend here, for this particular example. It relies upon the names in `df` and `weights` being in the right order, but that can be arranged.

```
> nams <- names(weights)
> df[, nams] <- sweep(df[, nams], 2, unlist(weights), "*")
> df
  group age income assets
1     1 150   1000    500
2     2 200   3000    650
3     3 250   5000    800
```

If the variable names in `weights` and `df` are not in the same order, you can make them so:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(group = 1:3,
+                   age = seq(30, 50, length.out = 3),
+                   income = seq(100, 500, length.out = 3),
+                   assets = seq(500, 800, length.out = 3))
> nams <- c("age", "income") ## order in df2
> weights2 <- weights[, rev(nams)]
> weights2  ## wrong order compared to df2
  income age
1     10   5
> df2[, nams] <- sweep(df2[, nams], 2, unlist(weights2[, nams]), "*")
> df2
  group age income assets
1     1 150   1000    500
2     2 200   3000    650
3     3 250   5000    800
```

In other words we reorder all objects so that `age` and `income` are in the right order.

Comment: thanks @Gavin. (I did look at sweep before posting this, but did not understand the function at all). Could you please elaborate how not to rely on the order of the names? The original df could have 100s of columns, but weights could be only few and in any order.

Comment: See my update. The key is to make sure each object is in the correct order during the line of code. So set the order you want in `nams` then order all objects by `nams`.

Comment: thanks! I think this is a great solution and could work for many cases.

Comment: Nice. I hadn't ever seen `sweep()` before. Makes me feel like my answer is such an amateur one ;)

Answer (score 4):

Someone might have a slick way to do it with plyr, but this is probably the most straight forward way in base R.

```
shared.names <- intersect(names(df), names(weights))
cols <- sapply(names(df), USE.NAMES=TRUE, simplify=FALSE, FUN=function(name) 
        if (name %in% shared.names) df[[name]] * weights[[name]] else df[[name]])
data.frame(do.call(cbind, cols))

#   group age income assets
# 1     1 150   1000    500
# 2     2 200   3000    650
# 3     3 250   5000    800
```

Comment: Looks like we were thinking along the same general lines. I always forget about `intersect()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = 1:3, 
                 age = seq(30, 50, length.out = 3), 
                 income = seq(100, 500, length.out = 3), 
                 assets = seq(500, 800, length.out = 3))
weights <- data.frame(age = 5, income = 10)
```

The logic:

```
# Basic name matching looks like this
names(df[names(df) %in% names(weights)])
# [1] "age"    "income"

# Use that in `sapply()`
sapply(names(df[names(df) %in% names(weights)]), 
       function(x) df[[x]] * weights[[x]])
#      age income
# [1,] 150   1000
# [2,] 200   3000
# [3,] 250   5000
```

The implementation:

```
# Put it all together, replacing the original data
df[names(df) %in% names(weights)] <- sapply(names(df[names(df) %in% names(weights)]), 
                                            function(x) df[[x]] * weights[[x]])
```

The result:

```
df
#   group age income assets
# 1     1 150   1000    500
# 2     2 200   3000    650
# 3     3 250   5000    800
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a  `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
W <- data.table(weights)
```

Use `mapply` (or `Map`) to calculate the new columns and add then both at once
by reference.

```
DT <- data.table(df)
W <- data.table(weights)


DT[, `:=`(names(W), Map('*', DT[,names(W), with = F], W)), with = F]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in a for loop using an index resulting from which(%in%). The above approach is much more efficient but this is an alternative.

```
results <- list()
  for ( i in 1:length(which(names(df) %in% names(weights))) ) {
    idx1 <- which(names(df) %in% names(weights))[i]
      idx2 <- which(names(weights) %in% names(df))[i] 
    results[[i]] <- dat[,idx1] * weights[idx2] 
  } 
unlist(results)
```